# Como realmente posso integrar meu SQL Server com Push no Android?

Tags: android, sql-server, microsoft-azure, push-notification

Tenho uma tabela de pedido no meu banco do `SQL Server` e um aplicativo no `Android`. Toda vez que um pedido tiver alteração no status, o usuário recebe uma notificação.

Já criei o app pelo `GCM` da Google, peguei o `Key` e tudo mais, mas não entendo como fazer essa integração.

Tenho que fazer algo no meu banco? 
Crio um sistema em `ASP.NET` pra notificar quando eu inserir no banco?

Já tentei o `push` do `Azure`, mas ele dá um `javascript` ou um código `ASP.NET`.

Onde vou utilizar isso? 
Alguém consegue explicar de forma clara e detalhada esse processo?

Implementei alguns códigos na internet e tutoriais, mas específico com `SQL Server` e `Android` nunca encontrei. Tem pouca coisa na internet e aqui no StackOverflow vi pessoas falando sobre notificar na `Trigger`, mas como faço essa notificação no servidor do google pra que vá para o meu app?

Comment: Votei por deixar em aberto pois é possivel formular uma resposta semelhante a anterior citada mas para ambientes .NET por exemplo.

Comment: Você não entendeu amigo, acessar diretamente o sqlserver pelo android seria uma baita falha de segurança, o Azure dá estes códigos pra você usar do lado do servidor, ou seja, pra criar uma interação Android e banco em servidores é necessário um webservice, que é uma camada entre o banco e o android. Se você fizesse o acesso direto ao sqlserver qualquer um com algum conhecimento poderia capturar os dados de autenticação e poderia invadir o teu servidor. Veja se isto ajudar: https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-android-get-started-push/

Comment: Você está fazendo seu APP Android Nativo (Java) ou com alguma outra tecnologia tipo Xamarin ou Ionic?